# How to add press and long press gesture to NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a List of items in `NavigationView` like the code below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(id: item.id)) {
                        Text(item.name)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing special so far but in case I add the long press gesture action, then the `NavigationLink` destination is not called anymore when pressing the normal press gesture.

My question therefore is, how can be both actions installed? When the normal press action is triggered, then the ItemView should be called, whereas when the long press action is triggered, then the item which was long pressed should be added at the top of the list of items (like a favourite item). Furthermore an explanation would be really helpful to get a deeper knowledge about how SwiftUI works.

Comment: Have you tried `simultaneousGesture` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/simultaneousgesture?

Comment: I've tried this, but then scrolling on Apple Watch is not working anymore.